# how to test exception in python working with postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, exception

I have my own class *Article* designed to wrok with PostgreSQL. Each object created from the class is used to work with one row. Now I dont know how to test exception case. When I create such case:

```
article = Article(2)/*connects to the db and loads line with id 2*/
print article.title2 /*here my db does not have table title2 and should launch an error*/
```

it should throw error. And it does)
How should test case looks like? I use unittest. My test class with my wrong method which does not work is below:

```
import unittest
from article import * /*import my ORM class*/
class EntityTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Entity.db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='192.168.136.129' password='xxxxxxxxx'")/*creates connection to db*/
    def test_should_lounch_attr_error(self):
        article = Article(2)
        print article.title2
        self.assertRaisesRegex(article.AttributeError, "No attribute exists")
```

I have no expirience how to create test cases and no much good documentation of how to do it(((
As I undestood if testcase is passed (exception is generated), unittest should return Ok statement. Now it just shows error.

Comment: It shows error, because it's raised before your assert statement, on line `print article.title2`. Example of assertRaisesRegexp usage: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegexp

Comment: This doc was the first I checked) I tried to change to self.assertRaisesRegexp(article.AttributeError, "No attribute exists", article.atribute). The same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not supply a callable to `assertRaisesRegexp()` (N.B. `assertRaisesRegexp()`, not `assertRaisesRegex()`), then it acts as a context manager. In that case you should use a `with` statement like this:

```
import unittest
from article import * /*import my ORM class*/
class EntityTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Entity.db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='192.168.136.129' password='xxxxxxxxx'")/*creates connection to db*/
    def test_should_lounch_attr_error(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegexp(article.AttributeError, "No attribute exists"):
            article = Article(2)
            print article.title2
```

Unless your code can raise `article.AttributeError` with different string representations, I don't think that you actually need to use a regex for this. Just check for `article.AttributeError` with `assertRaises()`. This should suffice:

```
with self.assertRaisesRegexp(article.AttributeError):
    article = Article(2)
    print article.title2
```